# Recursive and regular languages

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, context-free

I'm trying to study for an exam and having difficulty with the following practice questions. Any help would be appreciated.

1. Give a language $L$ such that $L$ is not recursive but $\text{prefix}(L)$ is regular.
2. Give two languages $L_1$ and $L_2$, such that $L_1$ and $L_2$ are not recursive, but $L_1\cap L_2$ is recursive.
3. Give a language $L$ such that $L$ is regular but $\text{unary}(L)$ is not context-free.

Answer (score 2):

Tips.

1. *Any* (infinite) unary language has regular prefix language.
2. $L_1 = a \cdot K$ and similary 
   $L_2 = b \cdot K$  where $K$ is a well-chosen horrible language.

Question.

What is unary($L$)? If it is what I think, there is an easy example. Powers of two are not context-free: $\{ a^{2^n} \mid n\ge 1\}$.